# Combining 2 dummy variables

Tags: r, categorical-data, dummy-variable

I have 2 dummy variables and I would like to combine them in a way such that I have a new variable that puts a 1 if either Variable A or B had a 1.

e.g.

Variable A:
0
0
0
1
1

Variable B:
1 0 1 0 1

Variable C (ideally):
1 0 1 1 1

Any help is greatly appreciated! I know this is pretty simple.. getting back into R and feeling rusty!

Comment: `as.integer(A | B)` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with logical comparisons! The best one in this case is the OR operator, the pipe: |

```r
set.seed(1234)

var_a <- round(runif(10))
var_b <- round(runif(10))

var_c <- var_a|var_b

rbind(var_a, var_b, var_c)
```

[image]

This works because R automagically coerces the numeric 0 and 1s into logical FALSE and TRUE, which we then compare using OR before automagically coercing back into numeric.

Welcome back to R!

Comment: Thank you so much!! Very helpful :)

Comment: If this solved your problem, feel free to hit the green check mark so others know it works!